# How do I get the value of the parent into its children function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I am creating a Router based on Express Router that will function like Laravel's.

I want to be able to write code like:

```
Route.group("/api", () => {
    Route.get("/auth/login", myLoginFunction)
    Route.get("/auth/register", myRegisterFunction)
})
```

But how do I find out which group the routes are called under? My Route class looks like this:

```
export class Route {
    #routes: Array<IRoute>;
    
    public static group(name: string, cb: Function) {
        
    }

    public static get(name: string, cb: Function) {

    }
}
```

And I was thinking I would prepend the group name to each route, but I don't know how to access group name in each subroute. Any suggestions?

Comment: Rather than group/ get being static, they could be functions on a "route group" object. That way when you call `aGroup.get(..` it has the info it needs to build up the complete path.

Comment: true, but i want to do it laravel way

Comment: Given they're static methods, the only reasonable way is to have a static stack of groups which is a bit of an anti-pattern in JS. That's also how laravels source does it, so if you _really_ want to do it that way, just port [the laravel source](https://github.com/illuminate/routing/blob/master/Router.php).

Comment: Thanks a lot, but im gonna learn from how adonisjs do it, its pretty smart: https://github.com/adonisjs/http-server/blob/eb89bd3d2b28b531c68a382ad6148807e8852dd0/src/Router/index.ts

Answer (score 1):

I found a versatile solution after looking at how AdonisJS implemented the router.
Here's my final code for reference, and is used like so:

```
import {Router} from "fastia/kernel/RouteServiceProvider";

Router.group("api", () => {
    Router.group("auth", () => {
        Router.get("login", (_, res) => {
            return res.send({
                message: "hello"
            })
        }).middleware(["has:testquery", "admin"])
        Router.get("register", () => null).middleware(["has:funquery"])
        Router.group("password", () => {
            Router.get("forgot", () => null)
            Router.get("reset", () => null)
        })
    })
    Router.get("test", () => null)
})
```

Router code:

```
import {Router as ExpressRouter} from "express";
import {IMiddlewareCollection} from "../middleware/IMiddleware";

export class RouteGroup {
    public routes: (Route | RouteGroup)[] = [];
    public name;

    constructor(name: string) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public populate(route: (Route | RouteGroup), params: string) {
        if (route instanceof RouteGroup) {
            route.routes.forEach(child => this.populate(child, params));
            return;
        }

        route.prefix(params);
    }
}

export class Route {
    public prefixes: string[] = [];
    public path: string;
    public method: string;
    public handler: Function;
    public middlewares?: Array<string>;

    constructor(path: string, method: string, handler: Function, middlewares?: Array<string>) {
        this.path = path;
        this.method = method;
        this.handler = handler;
        this.middlewares = middlewares;
        this.prefixes.push(this.path)
    }

    public prefix(path: string) {
        this.prefixes.unshift(path);
    }

    public getPath() {
        return "/" + this.prefixes.join("/")
    }

    public middleware(middlewares: Array<string>) {
        this.middlewares = middlewares;
    }
}

export class Router {
    public routes: (Route | RouteGroup)[] = [];
    public openedGroups: Array<RouteGroup> = [];
    private router: ExpressRouter = ExpressRouter();
    private middlewareCollection: IMiddlewareCollection;
    public static instance: Router;

    public setMiddlewares(middlewareCollection: IMiddlewareCollection) {
        this.middlewareCollection = middlewareCollection;
    }

    private getRecentGroup() {
        return this.openedGroups[this.openedGroups.length - 1];
    }

    private route(path: string, method: string, handler: Function) {
        const route = new Route(path, method, handler);
        const openedGroup = this.getRecentGroup();
        if (openedGroup) {
            openedGroup.routes.push(route)
        } else {
            this.routes.push(route)
        }

        return route;
    }

    public _get(path: string, handler: Function) {
        return this.route(path, "get", handler);
    }

    public _group(name: string, cb: Function) {
        const group = new RouteGroup(name);

        const openedGroup = this.getRecentGroup();
        if (openedGroup) {
            openedGroup.routes.push(group)
        } else {
            this.routes.push(group);
        }

        this.openedGroups.push(group);

        cb();

        this.openedGroups.pop();

        group.populate(group, group.name);
    }

    public static group(name: string, cb: Function) {
        return this.getInstance()._group(name, cb);
    }

    public static get(path: string, handler: Function) {
        return this.getInstance()._get(path, handler);
    }

    private parseRoute(route: (Route | RouteGroup)) {
        if (route instanceof RouteGroup) {
            route.routes.forEach(child => this.parseRoute(child))
        } else {
            console.log(route.getPath());
            if (route.middlewares?.length) {
                const middlewares: Function[] = [];
                route.middlewares.forEach(x => {
                    if (this.middlewareCollection[x]) {
                        middlewares.push(this.middlewareCollection[x].handle);
                    }
                })
                this.router[route.method](route.getPath(), ...middlewares, route.handler);
            } else {
                this.router[route.method](route.getPath(), route.handler);
            }
        }
    }

    public run() {
        this.routes.forEach(route => this.parseRoute(route));
    }

    public getRouter() {
        return this.router
    }

    public static create() {
        this.instance = new this();
        return this.instance
    }

    public static getInstance() {
        return this.instance
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define static variable(s) before calling group callback for configuration of the groups, like `prefix`.

Minor changes to your template include:

1. keep `#routes` static, otherwise it won't be accessible without instantiating `Route`
2. Javascript doesn't have `public` keyword.

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@babel/standalone/babel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel">
class Route {
    static #prefix='';
    static #routes = [];
    // if using express.Router in backend.
    // static #expressRouter = express.Router();
    
    // prepare config variables for group
    static #prepareGroup(name: string = '') {
        Route.#prefix=name;
        Route.#prefix += name.endsWith('/') ? '' : '/';
    }
    
    static group(name: string, cb: Function) {
        Route.#prepareGroup(name);
        cb();
        Route.#prepareGroup();
    }

    static get(name: string, cb: Function) {
      Route.#routes.push({
        path: `${Route.#prefix}name`,
        method: 'GET',
        cb
      });
      // or if using `expressRouter`, use instead
      // expressRouter.get(name, cb);
    }
    
    static _showRoutes() {
      console.log(Route.#routes);
    }
}

// dummy functions
const myLoginFunction = () => {}
const myRegisterFunction = () => {}

Route.group("/api", () => {
    Route.get("/auth/login", myLoginFunction)
    Route.get("/auth/register", myRegisterFunction)
})
Route._showRoutes()
</script>
```